# STM32YYXX chip series is not defined in boards.txt

Tags: programming

The STM32YYXX chip series is not defined in `boards.txt`? How can I solve this? I am using Windows 10 with Arduino IDE 1.6.6

Comment: what boards.txt?

Comment: Did the answer help? If so then please upvote and mark as the accepted answer. If you found an alternative method, then please post that as an answer and mark *that* as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Overview

Following the guide [Getting Started](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32#getting-started) on the STM32 page on Github: [Arduino core support for STM32 based boards](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32):

> This repo is available as a package usable with [Arduino Boards
>   Manager](https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/cores).
>
> Use this link in the "Additional Boards Managers URLs" field:
>
> [`https://github.com/stm32duino/BoardManagerFiles/raw/master/STM32/package_stm_index.json`](https://github.com/stm32duino/BoardManagerFiles/raw/master/STM32/package_stm_index.json)
>
> For full instructions on using the "Boards Manager", see the [Getting
>   Started](https://github.com/stm32duino/wiki/wiki/Getting-Started) page.

<sub>Thanks to Juraj's [comment](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/37622/juraj) for the tip</sub>

> <sub>this is not the current STM boards package. ST Microelectronic took over the development [github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32) [stm32duino.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=4671](http://stm32duino.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=4671)</sub>

#### Step by Step

The process is as follows (screenshots from OS X, but on Windows/Linux the process is the same):

Adding the URL in the preferences dialog (one URL per line)

> [image: STM32 - Additional Boards Manager URLs]

Boards Manager menu

> [image: STM32- Boards Manager menu]

Boards Manager dialog

> [image: STM32 - Boards Manager]

Boards Manager dialog - STM32 Core Boards installed

> [image: STM32 - STM32 Cores selected]

Boards Manager dialog - Boards installing

> [image: STM32 - STM32 Cores installing]

Boards Manager dialog - Boards installed

> [image: STM32 - STM32 Cores installed]

Here are the newly installed boards in the menu

> [image: STM32 - Boards Manager added boards]

As a comparison, these are the boards installed using the deprecated manual process described below:

> [image: STM32 - Manually added boards]

---

#### Deprecated method

<strike>From [STM32 - installation](https://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Installation)</strike>

> #### Prerequisites
>
> If your STM32 board does not have a bootloader yet and you want to be able to program it over USB, you'll have to upload
>   the STM32duino bootloader to flash memory. See [Burning the
>   bootloader](https://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Burning_the_bootloader).
>
> #### Arduino and Arduino_STM32
>
> - Download and install the official [Arduino IDE](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software). Versions 1.6.10 till 1.8.5 have been reported to work fine.
>
>   - If you already have the Arduino IDE installed and it's a newer version, see the [Boards Manager package](https://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Boards_Manager_package) method of installation.
>
>     - Note: this method is deprecated and not supported in forum!
> - Run Arduino IDE, and open the menu **Tools -> Boards -> Boards Manager**. Install the "Arduino SAM Boards" package (includes the
>     Arduino Due) from the list of available boards. This installs compiler
>     support for ARM Cortex-M3.
> - Download a zip file containing the Arduino STM32 files from [here](https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32/archive/master.zip).
> - Unzip the content of the zip file, and place the Arduino_STM32 folder to `[Arduino sketches folder]/[hardware]/[Arduino_STM32]`.
>     Create the '`hardware`' folder if it does not exist yet.
>
> Example how the path should look like:
>   `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Arduino\hardware\Arduino_STM32`

---

As an aside, for anyone using OS X, from [Installation on OSX](https://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Installation_on_OSX)

> #### Installation on OSX
>
> - `Arduino_STM32` folder must be placed inside
>     `~/Documents/Arduino/hardware` (note. if the hardware folder doesn't
>     exist you will need to create it)
> - So you should get `~/Documents/Arduino/hardware/Arduino_STM32`
> - Note.  DFU util binaries
>     have now been added to the repo, in `tools/macosx/dfu-util`, so there is
>     no longer a need to install Homebrew to then install `dfu-util`, or to
>     compile `dfu-util` from source.

Comment: I recommend the Boards Manager package method of installation.

Comment: It says that the Boards Manager method is depreciated. Is that incorrect?

Comment: this is not the current STM boards package. ST Microelectronic took over the development https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32 http://stm32duino.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=4671

Comment: You should post that as an answer then, as mine seems to be out of date.

Comment: If the downvoter could explain why the downvote or better still post an answer then that would be most helpful. A warm thanks.

Comment: @Juraj - I think I may may encounter a similar issue as the OP, I need to code up (what I believe to be) a Maple Mini board, but which has been customised with a 303 rather than a 103... and there doesn't seem to be that option available after installing the package, using the method described in my answer (I haven't tried your github link yet).I may need to post my own (similar) question.

Comment: the ST package has Boards Manager installation and is up-to-date. with F303 too

Comment: Ah OK, thanks. I'll give it a go. If that all works fine, I might update/correct my answer with your (github) suggestion, and credit your comment for it, if you don't mind...?